# Google scripting | Move a file that is older than a day into another folder

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting

So I've been trying to come together with this script from multiple sources but it just doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var fileIDs = [];
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*1*1;
  var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('15CqfGbLtBVu3B6-4IGALRMOKJGkhXczF');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('creationDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
    Logger.log('ID: ' + file.getId() + ', Name: ' + file.getName());
  }
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("15CqfGbLtBVu3B6-4IGALRMOKJGkhXczF")

  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).makeCopy(DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getName());
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).setTrashed(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include any specific error messages, the expected behavior, and the actual observed behavior for any attempts you have made to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will get fileIds of your day old files.

```
function getDayOldFileIds() {
  var fileIdsA=[]
  var currdate=new Date();
  var oldDate = new Date(currdate.valueOf() - 86400000);//86400000 milliseconds in a day
  var cutOffDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('15CqfGbLtBVu3B6-4IGALRMOKJGkhXczF');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('creationDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIdsA.push(file.getId());
  }
  return fileIdsA;
}
```

If you wish to make backups of files this routine has been working pretty well for me. And I added the line to trash them if you wish.  This routine also supports team drives.

```
function moveFilesToBackupFolder(fileIdsA){
  var backUpFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('BackupDirId'));
  var subFldrName='FilesBackup' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss');
  var subFldr=backUpFolder.createFolder(subFldrName);
  for(var i=0;i<fileIdsA.length;i++){
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileIdsA[i]);
    var copyName=file.getName();
    var res=file.makeCopy(copyName,subFldr);
    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
      Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": subFldr.getId()}]}, res.getId(), null, {"supportsTeamDrives":true});
    }
    file.setTrashed(true);//remove this if you dont want to trash them
  }
}
```